# Have the sales of "Shape of water" dildos skyrocketed due to the success of the film with that name?

Tags: sexuality

[Breitbart](http://www.breitbart.com/big-hollywood/2018/03/06/shape-of-water-themed-dildo-sales-skyrocket-following-oscars-success/) reports:

> Sales of dildo sex toys inspired by the Academy Award-winning film Shape of Water have skyrocketed following its success at the Oscars, The Wrap reports.
>   The dildos, which are inspired by a character known as the ‘Amphibian Man,’ reportedly sold out within 20 minutes of the film being awarded the Oscar for Best Picture at Sunday’s award ceremony.
>
> “Our sales have gone through the roof!” the dildo’s sculptor told the outlet. “All ‘Shape of Water’ toys sold out as soon as I posted them… in less than 20 minutes!”

Is this a true story?

Comment: Breitbart cites as source www.thewrap.com web site where it's corroborated, as if it's notable or not I think it fulfills the rules for asking on this web site, but I might be wrong, so it's up for an admin.

Comment: If you keep following the links, you find that the makers only manufacture 20 of that toy at the time. The company is just a couple — in other words: two people — that make these toys. I do not know about you but I find that two-digit sales numbers for such a small company does not really make for a notable claim.

Comment: Ah, you are right I didn't realize that, I'll vote for closing this question then, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Also if you really want to know, send a message to the Etsy account that markets the toys and ask. Ain't no better place to get information than directly from the primary source. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74143/discussion-between-michaelk-and-user2638180).

Comment: @MichaelK That sounds like the answer to the question. The claim is 'notable' in that it was made by a site with a substantial readership (many of whom believe what it says); that the article misrepresents double-digit sales as "skyrocketing" means it's *misleading*, and deserves a debunking answer (not unnotable within the rules of this site, that rule exists to prevent questions like "My mate Dave reckons...")

Comment: I'm personally satisfied that it is a notable claim. Breitbart is widely read. We can expect many people will believe what they write. So it is worth confirming or debunking.

Comment: Commenters: if you are thinking of posting another prurient or jocular comment about the subject matter, please don't.

Comment: @Oddthinking : I think the issue with notability is not because of the source (even if I'm no fan of Breitbart), but because of the lack of interest of the claim. Whether or not a few dozen of an inexpensive item have been sold doesn't seem to be a worthy subject. A bit as if I was asking if it has really been raining in NY the 3rd of June 2014, providing a weather channel link as a source : is that notable enough ? (I've other stupid examples!)

Comment: @Evargalo But Breitbart are talking as if those few dozen sales are an eye-opening new craze with "skyrocketing" sales, when actually all that has happened is a dozen or so people bought some novelty. That's the whole point of the question. The fact a claim is false and the answer is boring doesn't invalidate the question: same as if a site claimed there was a monsoon and flooding in NY on 3rd June when actually there was just drizzle. We'd debunk the false claim, with the (boring) truth.

Comment: @user568458 : I appreciate that, and we actually have enough matter in MichaelK's comment for an answer. I was just answering Oddthinking's remark. (And the 3rd of June *was* a big issue because I had forgotten my umbrella on that day.)

Comment: Let's move the discussion about notability [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74199/discussion-on-question-by-user2638180-have-the-sales-of-shape-of-water-dildos).